# Messages are not rendered after I changed page mapping from controller methods to explicit view page

Tags: grails, message

I changed mapping of my page in UrlMappings to the following value:

```
name producingCountry: "${adminArea}/producing-country/$id" (controller: "producingCountry", view: "/producingCountry/show") {
    constraints { id(matches: /\d+/) }
}
```

The page (/producingCountry/show) is as simple as:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <title><g:message code="producingCountry.show.title"/></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The message is not rendered any more. It worked fine when its url was mapped to controller method 'show' with the very last line like:

```
render [producingCountry: (country)]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use this mapping

```
"/${adminArea}/producing-country/$id" (controller: "producingCountry", view: "show")
```

When `controller` is specified, the `view` takes the name instead of the relative path.

**UPDATE**
I am not sure about how `adminArea` is evaluated, but the below works for me:

```
//UrlMapping:- [mark the "/" in the beginning of the mapping, it is required to append to root context]
name producingCountry: "/admin/producing-country/$id" (controller: "producingCountry", view: "show") {
                constraints { id(matches: /\d+/) }
        }

//show.gsp
Exactly same (copied) from your question.

//messages.properties
producingCountry.show.title=United States
```

Gives me a page with title `United States` when below url pattern is hit:

`http://localhost:8080/DemoUrlMappingApp/admin/producing-country/123`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't specify controller parameter when you specify a view name in urlMapping definition, try this:

```
"/${adminArea}/producing-country/$id" (view: "/producingCountry/show")
```